# If Full Time Then Button Color is Blue But If Part Time Button Color is Red

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core

In my template I want  if `span` content have "full time job" then Button  color  is blue else  Button   color is red.

```
<div class="tag MB-3"><i class="nil-tag"></i>
  <%=Job-data. Rows[i]["date"] %>
</div>

<span class="full-time"><%=Job-data. Rows[i]["Time"] %></span>
</div>
<div class="tag MB-3"><i class="nil-tag"></i> </div>
<span class="full-time">full time</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? Please provide the details as much as possible, when asking a question, and show that what you have done so far to resolve the problem. Based on that information, experts on StackOverflow can help you better. Have a look at the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use classes for this, if you have access to the HTML. Consider
>   this:
>
> ```
> <p class="normal">Text</p>
>
> <p class="active">Text</p> and in your CSS file:
>
>
> p.normal {
>   background-position : 150px 8px;
> }
> p.active {
>   background-position : 4px 8px;
> }
> ```
>
> That's the CSS way to do it.
>
> Then there are CSS preprocessors like Sass. You can use conditionals
>   there, which'd look like this:
>
> ```
> $type: monster;
> p {
>   @if $type == ocean {
>     color: blue;
>   } @else if $type == matador {
>     color: red;
>   } @else if $type == monster {
>     color: green;
>   } @else {
>     color: black;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Disadvantages are, that you're bound to pre-process your stylesheets,
>   and that the condition is evaluated at compile time, not run time.
>
> A newer feature of CSS proper are custom properties (a.k.a. CSS
>   variables). They are evaluated at run time (in browsers supporting
>   them).
>
> With them you could do something along the line:
>
> ```
> :root {
>   --main-bg-color: brown;
> }
>
> .one {
>   background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
> }
>
> .two {
>   background-color: black;
> }
> ```
>
> Finally, you can preprocess your stylesheet with your favourite
>   server-side language. If you're using PHP, serve a style.css.php file,
>   that looks something like this:
>
> ```
> p {
>   background-position: <?php echo (@$_GET['foo'] == 'bar')? "150" : "4"; ?>px 8px;
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, you will however have a performance impact, since
>   caching such a stylesheet will be difficult.